# Delaying waitForKeyElement? tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm currently working with

```
waitForKeyElements ("#ButtonID", Function1);
```

which basically keeps searching for Button and then executes function1. But- Is there a way to delay waitforkeyElements to 100ms? So it searches every 100ms, instead of constantly.

Comment: Actually, waitForKeyElements searches every 300 ms, not constantly. And, if you use `waitForKeyElements ("#ButtonID", Function1, true)`, it unloads after the first time it finds ButtonID.

Comment: Oh really? I was not aware of this. But there is no way to 'alter' the search speed?

Comment: The only way to alter the search speed is to fork the source code and use your own version (which is easy enough, several people have done this, though most just copy the code untouched). ... The 300 ms is proven over years of use and testing, and it is based on usability studies and browser impact studies. ... Anyway, what is your real problem?  Delaying the waitForKeyElements cycle is not a problem, it is a sub-optimal attempt to solve something. What is that something?

Comment: @brockadams I am currently working on a script, which automatically searches for my button. However due to optimization i don't want it checking all the time (Or every 300ms as i just learned) I want to delay it even further.

Comment: Well, you need to edit your question to show (A) **How much** you want to "delay" it, (B) **When** to do so, and (C) **Why** you think this is necessary. ... Then comment here so that we know to check the edit.